# Disable paged searches in OpenLDAP

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am using [osixia/openldap](https://github.com/osixia/docker-openldap) for testing purposes, and I would like to disable paged search results.

According to the [documentation](https://openldap.org/doc/admin24/limits.html), it should be possible to do this on a global level using the `olcSizeLimit` attribute.

Here is my LDIF file (mounted in /container/service/slapd/assets/config/bootstrap/ldif/custom/disable-paging.ldif):

```
dn: cn=config
changeType: modify
add: olcSizeLimit
olcSizeLimit: size.prtotal=disabled
```

The container starts properly with this LDIF file:

```
sample-ldap-main_1  | Processing file /container/run/service/slapd/assets/config/bootstrap/ldif/custom/disable-paging.ldif
sample-ldap-main_1  | modifying entry "cn=config"
```

But when I attempt a search with the Simple Paged Results control, the search succeeds without any errors.

I came accross an [email thread](https://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-technical/201509/msg00005.html) on this topic, but it didn't seem to lead anywhere. Has anyone gotten this working before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach actually works, when I attempt to run a paged search programmatically ([go-ldap](https://github.com/go-ldap/ldap)) I get the following error:

```
LDAP Result Code 11 "Admin Limit Exceeded": pagedResults control not allowed
```

I was attempting to test this configuration with Apache Directory Studio, which wasn't failing on paged searches for some reason. I suspect it might have  a "convenience" feature where if a paged search fails it automatically omits the search control and tries again?